# How to take screen shots of logcat with eclipse(Helios)

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Sorry to ask such a bad question.But i do not know how to take images of logcat from eclipse while running android project.Can anyone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `printscreen` functionality of the system or you can get all the logcat entries:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (select all).
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (copy).
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste) it in your notepad.

Comment: Actually i need the format of the errors in which it is thr in logcat.When u will copy and paste it is coming but not arranged properly

Comment: You can use print screen functionality and crop the extra portion of the image and it will give the logcat as you see.

Comment: how to use printscreen functionality? I dont have any idea will u please give me any idea if u have plz?

Comment: press print screen key of your keyboard and then open mspaint and paste it there and save the image.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you like ctrl+A, ctrl+c?

Comment: Actually i need the format of the errors in which it is thr in logcat.When u will copy and paste it is coming but not arranged properly

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your question properly but I think that what you are looking for is to copy logcat from eclipse. To do that, double click on logcat tab and select the lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to windows-> show view -> other -> LogCat.
- In Logcat we just use ctrl+c and ctrl+v keys to copy and paste the
  specified line.
- Using the Shift key to copy the entire lines in LogCat.